# Stored procedure insert into function

Tags: sql, join, primary-key

I have two tables

- First table is `CUSTOMERS` with columns `CustomerId, CustomerName`
- Second table is `LICENSES` with columns `LicenseId, Customer`

The column `Customer` in the second table is the `CustomerId` from the First table

I wanted to create a stored procedure that insert values into table 2

```
Insert into Licenses (Customer)
Values(CustomerId)
```

How can I get this data from the other table?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Seems like you accepted an answer to soon. Regardless you'll need to clarify your question. What data do you want to get from the other table? All Customers? What is the exact input data for this stored procedure?

Comment: I was excited when i thought it works. The column Customer= CustomerId from the customers table. i.e, If the CustomerId=5,CustomerName= A then the LicensedId=(anything) and the Customer= 5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks to me like simply a syntax question - I think what you want is

```
INSERT INTO Licenses (Customer) SELECT CustomerId FROM customers where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertToTable
    @CustomerID INT OUTPUT,
    @CustomerName VARCHAR(50),
    @LicenseID INT,

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
            VALUES (@CustomerName);
            SET @CustomerID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            INSERT INTO LICENSES
            VALUES (@LicenseID, @CustomerID)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END

    END CATCH;
END;
 ];
```

if CustomerID is identity, I wish that it will be work... :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `SQL Server` and your `PK` is autocorrelative using `identity(1,1)` do this:

```
CREATE PROC Register @CustomerName varchar(25)
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (Customer) VALUES (@CustomerName)
   INSERT INTO LICENSES (SELECT MAX(CustomerId) FROM CUSTOMERS)
END
```

But if you don't want to use `identity (1,1)` do this:

```
CREATE PROC Register @CustomerName varchar(25)
    AS BEGIN
       DECLARE @idc int = SELECT MAX(CustomerId) FROM CUSTOMERS;
       DECLARE @idl int = SELECT MAX(LicenseId) FROM LICENSES ;
       INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CustomerId, CustomerName) VALUES (@idc,@CustomerName)
       INSERT INTO LICENSES (LicenseId, Customer) VALUES (@idl,@idc)--I guess your field Customer is the foreign key
    END
```

Comment: No. Do not use MAX, us SCOPE_IDENTITY as shown below (which is also incorrect but at least it uses  SCOPE_IDENTITY(). There are many reasons for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought I got it but none of these solutions were correct. I tried to use SCOPE_IDENTITY but it didn't work with me either

Comment: I didn't know about SCOPE_IDENTITY @ElectricLlama, could you please explain me how it works, and why not to use MAX(); can i use it when i don't set my PK with an identity(1,1)?

Comment: If you have two users running that same proc at the same time they might both get an identical result out of MAX, whereas SCOPE_IDENTITY always gets the last identity value inserted in the batch (i.e. the connection or person running it)

Comment: but if i don't want to use identity what can i do?